# Arranging/styling checkboxes to be in two rows [Bootstrap & AngularJS]

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an AngularJS app on which I need to collect Day preferences from the user. I'm having trouble getting it laid out how I want it.

The days array has 8 items (7 + "All"), and I want it arranged in 2 rows of 4. How can I get it to split itself so it's inline for the 4, but then breaks into a new row? I'd like to do this without hard coding all of the days since it's easier to relate to my model this way.

And here's the incorrect (current) layout, and how I want it to look...
[image: Incorrect layout]
[image: What I want it to look like]

```
    <div class="form-group checkbox">
        <p class="h2">When do you usually like to lunch?</p>
        <label ng-repeat="day in days" class="sm" ng-click="dayClicked(day)">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   value="{{day.name}}"
                   ng-model="day.selected">
            {{day.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: why is your input wrapped by your label? why not use a unordered list and repeat li and each li has a label and an input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this.

```css
label.sm {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
label.sm:last-child:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Added explanation**

The first rule, `label.sm`, targets each of your labels. It modifies the default display of a label so it will have a specific width. You can technically use `display: inline-block`, but some older browsers (*cough cough* IE) don't respect that. Combine `display: block` with `float: left` to emulate `display: inline-block`. Specifying `width: 25%` makes each label one-fourth (100% / 4 = 25%) the width of the available space in its container.

The second rule, `label.sm:last-child:after` targets the last of the labels in the group and creates a pseudo-element (an element that isn't in the HTML). The pseudo-element has a single space for its contents, spans the width of its container, has no height, hides anything outside of the space it's been given (which is nothing), and clears the float flag set by the labels.

Comment: wow that totally works perfectly. I'd love to understand why it's working... I'm guessing something related to the width:25%, elsewise nothing in there shows me why it would break half way to add the :after? Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaOhana I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: perfect thanks, wish I could give more than one upvote